# Insufficient Permission [403] sending email

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to send emails in my web app (currently in localhost), I'm using the next code that I used (and its working) for a console app, it should open a webpage asking for google account:

```
public async Task<String> SendEmail(String from, String text)
{
    try
    {
        UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "-------------",
                ClientSecret = "----------"
            },
            new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString()));

        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        string plainText = "To: -------@gmail.com," + from + "\r\n" +
                           "Subject: T2S\r\n" +
                           "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n\r\n" +
                           text;

        var newMsg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
        newMsg.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(plainText.ToString());
        service.Users.Messages.Send(newMsg, "me").Execute();
        return "Done";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return "False";
    }
}

private string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
{
    var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "");
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>
> Insufficient Permission [403]
>
> Errors [Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]

Comment: How is the web application supposed to open up the GMail webpage?

Comment: for the console application is automatic

Comment: change "user", to  "XXXX" and try and reauthorize for me please let me know if that fixes it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the .net client library automatically handles opening the window for google authentication.  as for sending requiring opening gmail webpage it doesnt this is the gmail api.

Comment: @DaImTo That makes sense on a console, i.e user application, not on a hosted application where there shouldn't be any user logged-in to see a new Chrome window popup...

Comment: Even a hosted application will have a user to login you cant access private user data without being authenticated. The default browser will have to popup. Unless you are talking about using server to service communication which would require the use of a service account.   which he is not using here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) indeed it worked perfectly fine with the change:

**change "user", to "XXXX"**